# connection and session closing

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have the following code in the `Try` bloc :

```
// Session variable
Session session = null;
// Connection variable
Connection conn = null;

try {
...
// Get hibernate session
session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
// Get connection frojm session
conn = session.connection();
...
}catch{
...
}
```

And in the `finally` bloc i want to bloc all the related object of the connection with the database.

the closing of session makes us to close the connection ? or we have to have to close the connection before ? 
***Solution 1 :***

```
finally{
try{if (conn!=null) conn.close();}ctach{}
try{if (session!=null) session.close();}catch{}
}
```

***Solution 2 :***

```
finally{
try{if (session!=null) session.close();}catch{}
}
```

In case of one of the two solutions before, can you explain the relationship between session and connection specially through pool way.

Comment: Is this java? you haven't tagged it as such.

Comment: yes, of course java i already added the java tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second approach is enough. If you haven't set [hibernate.connection.release_mode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-jdbc-properties), then default (auto) is used. According documentation:

> By default, a JDBC connection is held until the session is explicitly
>   closed or disconnected.

In case of pool, closing connection means that connection is returned to pool.

Answer (score 1):

First, I like to know why you want to close connection in the code mentioned?

When you close a session hibernate makes sure that it does not hold any reference to the connection. In Hibernate 3.6.8, the call is delegated to the ConnectionManager. Check [closeConnection() method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.8.Final/org/hibernate/jdbc/ConnectionManager.java#ConnectionManager.closeConnection%28%29). In Hibernate 4 when you call  `session.connection()` what you get is a proxy and in hibernate 3, you are most likely get wrapper over connection, if connection pool is configured.

So your option is to debug `session.connection()` and `session.close()`, and decide whether you want to close the coneection or not.With the kind of information you provided, any answer here will be pure assumption.